# Android ScrollViews with 50%+ height

Tags: android-layout, android-xml, android-scrollview

I need to create an Android layout with two ScrollViews arranged vertically. If the device screen is small - each of them should occupy 50% of the screen (picture 1). But if the screen height allows, the lower ScrollView (tableview) should stretch to the remaining free space (picture 2). The basic example that is used now is given below, but it just splits the screen 50/50 in any case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".cards.CardGoods">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:menu="@menu/card_step1_menu"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingStart="32dp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/card_goods_p1"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
                />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/divider_height"
                android:background="@drawable/horizontal_gradient_menu_divider_02" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/card_Code_n"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/barcode24px"
                        app:startIconTint="@color/deep_purple_100"
                        >

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/card_Code"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:hint="@string/code"
                            android:maxLines="2"
                            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                            android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/lL_edit2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        >

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn_ean13"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/card_Ean13"
                            android:padding="8dp"
                            />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn_edit_userInfo4"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:padding="8dp"
                            android:text="@string/card_a1" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn_edit_userInfo4"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:padding="8dp"
                            android:text="@string/card_a2" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/card_Nt_n"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/shopping_basket24px"
                        app:startIconTint="@color/deep_purple_100">

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/card_Nt"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:hint="@string/name"
                            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                            android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/eiSpinnerLayout"
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/scale24px"
                        app:startIconTint="@color/deep_purple_100">

                        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
                            android:id="@+id/eiTextView"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            tools:ignore="KeyboardInaccessibleWidget"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:focusable="false"
                            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                            android:hint="@string/ei"
                            />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>
      
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/grey_400"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                <com.evrencoskun.tableview.TableView
                    android:id="@+id/tableview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    app:allow_click_inside_cell="true"
                    app:allow_click_inside_column_header="true"

                    app:allow_click_inside_row_header="true">
                </com.evrencoskun.tableview.TableView>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Pictuer 2]